# How to check in Swift an integer is in range of thousands?

Tags: swift, logic

In a loop I need to check if `n` index is a number in a range of thousands:

```
0...1000

1001...2000

2001...3000

and so on
```

How can I do that instead to define manually a range?

Comment: Why not just divide by 1000 and round to the nearest integer?

Comment: @tadman no need to round anything. It is already a result of an integer division.

Comment: @LeoDabus If it's an integer, sure, but without code it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: @tadman Question title "How to check in Swift an integer is in range of thousands?"

Comment: @LeoDabus I've learned to trust titles a lot less than code, but you have a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the range of numbers, I divided the number by 1000 and find the range according to the result.

```
let inputNumber = 6598

let dividedNumber: Float = Float(inputNumber) / 1000.0

if dividedNumber.rounded(.up) == dividedNumber.rounded(.down){
    //number is integer
    let end: Int = Int(dividedNumber.rounded(.down) * 1000)
    let start: Int = end - 1000
    print("Range is integer : ", (start + 1)...end)
    
} else {
    //number is not integer
    let start: Int = Int(dividedNumber.rounded(.down) * 1000)
    let end: Int = Int(start + 1000)
    print("Range is not integer : ", (start + 1)...end )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you to check if your number is in Thousands range or not

```
func checkNumberRange(withNumber myNumber: Double) {
   
//    let reminder = myNumber.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1) // if you wanna get reminder "Floating point"
   
    let start = floor(myNumber)
    let end = round(myNumber) + 1000
    if ((myNumber / 1000 >= 1) && (myNumber / 1000 <= 1000)) {
        print("range from \(start)...\(end)")
    }
    else {
        print("your number isn't in thousands range")
    }
    
}

checkNumberRange(withNumber: 10000067) //your number isn't in thousands range
checkNumberRange(withNumber: 12458.8) //range from 12458.0...13459.0
checkNumberRange(withNumber: 999) //your number isn't in thousands range
checkNumberRange(withNumber: 1000) //range from 1000.0...2000.0
```

I hope it will help you